# Can anyone help me how can I use jQuery-formBuilder plugin in meteor react app

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, meteor, formbuilder

I tried to use "https://formbuilder.online/" but got this error:

> addForm.jsx:10Uncaught TypeError: $(...).formBuilder is not a function

jQuery invaded component:

```
export default class AddForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props)

    }

    componentDidMount(){

        console.log('helo');

        $(".formBuilder").formBuilder();
    }
    render(){
        return(<div className="formBuilder"></div>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks a bit like you are including formBuilder after calling it. Are you sure the order is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomForm extends Component {
  fb = createRef();
  componentDidMount() {
   $(this.fb.current).formBuilder();
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="fb-editor" ref={this.fb} />;
  }
}
  export default CustomForm
```